# Pdf2json integrated with Protactor

Tags: npm, protractor

Has someone integrated `pdf2json` npm package with Protractor? I have been able to create a standalone node application to convert a PDF to json.

What I'm trying to do now is to add `pdf2json` to `protractor.config.js` and be able to use it in my test specs.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work myself so I thought to post what I did just in case someone needs the same.

Add the following to the Protractor config file

```
// PDF Parser
var PDFParser = require("pdf2json");
global.pdfParser = new PDFParser();
```

In the spec, we just need to wait for the async call to load the PDF to finish - note the `done()` (see [Jasmine Async Support](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support)). The spec would look like:

```
var fs = require('fs');    

describe('PDF Parser', function() {

    it ("The spec", function(done){
        // Capture the error
        pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", errData => {
            console.error(errData);
            done();
        });

        // Transform to json
        pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
            fs.writeFile("path/to/save/json/file", JSON.stringify(pdfData));
            done();
        });

        // This is an async call. We have to wait for it, so we use done in the 'it'
        pdfParser.loadPDF("path/to/pdf/file");
    });

});
```

Comment: where is pdfParser defined in your spec? I cannot see the connection with global.pdfParser